# Location of files in classpath section of web.xml inside WAR (spring application)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. While going through an application I found that its web.xml contains the following -

```
<context-param>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/abc/def/ghijkl.xml            
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am trying to understand that when you build a WAR of this application, does the ghijkl.xml file get compiled too?
I have been digging into the WAR and havent found any refernce to the xml files there.
Can someone please guide me through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context parameters which can be read from all servlets in your application, in Spring project this is used as below.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

You declare all servlets can access too these beans which are defined in context.xml.

> I am trying to understand that when you build a WAR of this
>   application, does the ghijkl.xml file get compiled too?

xml files are not compiled, they are used in runtime when the application is start(deploy to application server and initial start)

> I have been digging into the WAR and havent found any refernce to the
>   xml files there

It should some reference if it is not you get an runtime exception when you start your application like below stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/abc/def/ghijkl.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/abc/def/ghijkl.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [sasa.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Thank you. That cleared my concepts to a lot extent.